# Операторы сравнения.почему постоянно false

Tags: javascript

почему всегда false даже если num равен 5. что бы не вводил всегда false

```
const input = document.querySelector(".i-1").value;
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let out = document.querySelector(".out");

button.onclick = () => {
  let num = +input.value;
  if (num == 5) {
    out.innerHTML = true;
  } else {
    out.innerHTML = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Ну отладчик же существует...

Answer (score 4):

Переменная `num` имеет значение `NaN`, потому что Ваш код делает вот это:

```
... = inputElement.value.value;
```

---

Исправление:

```
const input = document.querySelector(".i-1"); // !!!
```