# Не перезаписывает содержимое DIV

Tags: javascript

При нажатии `<button>` выполняется функция `f1()`. Функция получает `div.out-3` со страницы и в каждый записывает число ***3***, перезаписывая содержимое `<div>`:

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#b-1").onclick = f1;

function f1() {
  let ot = 3;
  let out = document.getElementsByClassName("out-3");
  for (let i = 0; i < ot.length; i++) {
    out.innerHTML += ot[i];
  }
  console.log(out);
}
```

```html
<div class="out-3">1</div>
<div class="out-3">1</div>
<div class="out-3">2</div>
<button id="b-1">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152900/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-false

Comment: @Igor: у человека не хватает репы минусануть :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("#b-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const ot = 3;
  document.querySelectorAll(".out-3").forEach(el => el.innerHTML = ot);
});
```

```html
<div class="out-3">1</div>
<div class="out-3">1</div>
<div class="out-3">2</div>
<button id="b-1">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: спасибо.так все просто)

Comment: @ВадимУманский Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
out.innerHTML += ot[i];
```

Здесь вместо "+=" просто нужно писать "=" и все.