# нужно через forEach вывести только числа из массива

Tags: javascript

```js
let a3 = [2, "hello", 3, "hi", 4, "Mazai"];
let a3_res = a3.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  if (a3 == Number) {
    console.log(elem);
  }
});
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152900/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если У Вас задача сделать это именно при помощи forEach, то элементы в новый массив нужно добавлять принудительно, поскольку forEach это метод, который просто проходит по массиву, ничего не возвращая.

```
let a3 = [2, "hello", 3, "hi", 4, "Mazai"];
let a3_res = [];
a3.forEach(function(elem) {
  if(typeof elem == "number") a3_res.push(elem);
});
console.log(a3_res);
```

Comment: Я вас благодарю))))

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a3 = [2, "hello", 3, "hi", 4, "Mazai"];
let a3_res = a3.filter(function(elem) {
  return typeof elem == "number";
});
console.log(a3_res);
```

Comment: просто `filter(Number)` не пойдет?

Comment: у меня задача выглядит так (Дан массив a3 = [2, "hello", 3, "hi", 4, "Mazai"] - с помощью forEach переберите массив и создайте новый массив a3_res куда добавьте элементы данного массива являющиеся числом. Запускаться решение должно при вызове функции t3.)

Comment: @teran Может быть пойдет, если нужны и строки с числами.

Comment: @ВадимУманский вам тут продемонстрировали, что для определения числа вам не хватает `typeof` в сравнении.

Comment: @Igor и действительно :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a3 = [
           -Infinity,  // минус бесконечность
           false,      // не число
           NaN,        // не число
           2.4e-3,     // 0.0024
           '',         // не число
           '-1',       // не число
           null,       // не число
           0,          // 0
           Number,     // не число
           '1',        // не число
           undefined,  // не число
           2,          // 2
           "hello",    // не число
           3,          // 3
           Math.E,     // 2.7
           "hi",       // не число
           4,          // 4
           "Mazai",    // не число
           '2e5',      // не число
           Number(1),  // 1
           0xffff,     // 65535
           new Number, // 0
           true,       // не число
           Infinity,   // плюс бесконечность,
           23497654337n// не число 
         ];
const a3_res = [];
const isNum=v=>'[object Number]' == Object.prototype.toString.call(v) && ! isNaN(v);
a3.filter(isNum)
  .map(v=>+v)
  .forEach(v=>a3_res.push(v));
a3_res.forEach(v=>console.log(v));
```